# How to categorise a double (number) variable in R? I want to create a binomial category

Tags: r

I have a data of age and bmi (body mass index) of 66 individuals. Based on available knowledge bmi between 18.5 and 24.9 are normal. I wish to categorise as normal and abnormal bmi in R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
transform(df, type = c("abnormal", "normal")[(bmi >= 18.5 & bmi <= 24.9) + 1])

#  age  bmi     type
#1  12 15.6 abnormal
#2  10 19.2   normal
#3  31 23.3   normal
#4  56 25.0 abnormal
#5  19 18.0 abnormal
```

Or with simple `ifelse`

```
transform(df, type =ifelse(bmi >= 18.5 & bmi <= 24.9, "normal", "abnormal"))
```

---

We can also use `between` in `dplyr`/`data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(type = c("abnormal", "normal")[between(bmi, 18.5, 24.9) + 1])
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(12, 10, 31, 56, 19), bmi = c(15.6, 19.2, 23.3, 25, 18))
```